# Given a sparse csr matrix MS, how do i iterate through each row of MS?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a sparse matrix called MS, derived from a dense matrix of 5000x5000, and i want to iterate through each of its row (as a list or something else), so that i can perform other steps to it. Eg. Finding total count of each row.

I have tried looking at several API's online, but im still new to this, and have trouble interpreting/understanding them.

Is there anyway i can iterate through each row of my sparse csr matrix MS in python? Thank you in advance for any help/input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy

```
import numpy

new_MS = numpy.asarray(MS)
```

This will create a 1d array.

Then you can reshape the dimensions of column and row with,

```
new_ms = numpy.reshape(new_MS,(no_of_row,no_of_col))
```

This will create a 2d array of specifies rows and columns

Then iterate through columns like a simple c language on 2d array

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have attempted your suggestion but i got this error:

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1 into shape (5000,5000)

Comment: can you elaborate your question ?

Comment: Sure. So originally, i have a dense matrix M. Then i am required to transform it into a sparse matrix MS using "sparse.csr_matrix()". 

After transforming it into MS, now i want to iterate through each row of the sparse matrix and apply some basic functions to it. But i dont know how to iterate through the rows of the sparse matrix.